# Where can I find /Applications/XAMPP/Xamppfiles/?

Tags: php, html, macos, xampp

I have been told that in order to change the admin from "daemon" to anything else, I need to access /Applications/XAMPP/Xamppfiles/ on my Mac. All that I see in my Applications folder is the application XAMPP and no other folders. I've tried to find it in terminal and in the finder folder. How could I access this folder?

Comment: Mind the case-sensitivity in `xamppfiles`. What does `ls /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/` return for you? The list of files or "No such file or directory"?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't delete its content? what does that command in the terminal shows you: `ls -la /Applications/XAMPP/`? Also as Peter mentioned `xamppfiles` folder is lower case and in MacOS it is important.

Comment: @Petr sorry, my mistake. I did enter it correctly and it returns "No such file or directory"